# Iphone keeps reconnecting and disconnecting via USB

Tags: iphone, usb

Occasionally, when I connect my iPhone XR to Mac Book Pro (Mid-2015) model, the iPhone starts disconnecting and reconnecting.

It doesn't happen all the time, but it does usually happen once a day. Is there anyway to fix it?
Sometimes the iPhone won't be detected by the Mac at all, but this is much rarer.

I recently did a clean reinstall of MacOS Monterey, so that should probably rule out a lot of issues.

I only use the official lightning cable that comes with the iPhone. I have also checked the iPhone port has no dirt in it.

Thanks!

Comment: try a different port?  we have an older older MBP and on 1 of the ports the iPhone keeps connecting and disconnecting.  Switch ports, no problem. I have 2019 MBP, Monterey 12.13.1. and iPhone 13 pro and when I connect via cable i get the pop up window open and closes about 5-8 times before it stops....

Comment: Also try a different cable. It (and its connectors) are also subject to intermittent failure.

Comment: @Stumped when it happens if I try a different port, the problem is the same. Could that mean it’s more likely to be the phone that is the issue or the Mac that is the issue (or is it not possible to tell). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is not staying connected so that means something in the chain isn't functioning. Whether that's the MacBook's USB port, the cord, or your XR's dock, you would need to replace the faulty component.

I would make sure all the ports & connectors are clean. I would try a new cord (a few to be safe) using different ports on your MacBook. If that doesn't work then most likely you need to replace your phone's dock (part with the charging port).

If you have a good eye & a flashlight, you can look inside the ports to see if any of the metal pins are bent/missing, or corrosion (dusty green stuff). It's always a best bet to take them to to a repair shop to have them test the components using tools you might not have access to.